# Struggling to get checkbox and label to align in an inline Bootstrap form

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a minor annoyance on my form which I can't get rid of. The form is a set of "filters" so that the user can filter the table below. The label and checkbox marked don't align vertically. I've tried what I can to make them align but no luck.

[image: Bootstrap checkbox and label mis-alignment]

My Codepen:
https://codepen.io/rcx577/pen/PowJBwz

My HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="get">
    <!-- Action button placed inside of form so it renders inline with table filters -->
    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-sm-2" href="/journal/entries/new/" role="button">New Journal Entry</a>

        <label class="sr-only" for="id_user">User:</label>
        <select name="user" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="User" id="id_user">
            <option value="" selected>User</option>
            <option value="4">philip</option>
        </select>

        <label class="sr-only" for="id_type">Type:</label>
        <select name="type" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Type" id="id_type">
            <option value="">Type</option>
            <option value="BP">Bank Payment</option>
            <option value="BR">Bank Receipt</option>
            <option value="YE">Year End</option>
            <option value="JE">Journal Entry</option>
        </select>

        <label class="sr-only" for="id_datefrom">Datefrom:</label>
        <input type="date" name="datefrom" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Datefrom" id="id_datefrom">

        <label class="sr-only" for="id_dateto">Dateto:</label>
        <input type="date" name="dateto" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Dateto" id="id_dateto">

        <label class="sr-only" for="id_search">Search:</label>
        <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" id="id_search">

            <label class="sr-only" for="id_ledger">Ledger:</label>
            <select name="ledger" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Ledger" id="id_ledger">
                <option value="" selected>Ledger</option>
                <option value="3">Agata&#x27;s Account</option>
                <option value="5">Agata&#x27;s Credit Card</option>
                <option value="35">Agatas Float</option>
                <option value="75">Agatas Hobbies</option>
                <option value="23">Agatas Salary</option>
            </select>

            <label class="sr-only" for="id_project">Project:</label>
            <select name="project" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Project" id="id_project">
                <option value="" selected>Project</option>
                <option value="4">Project Icarus</option>
                <option value="5">Black Star</option>
            </select>


            <!-- THE ANNOYING CHECKBOX THAT I CAN'T ALIGN !!!!!!!!!!!! -->
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="id_is_reconcilied">Is reconcilied:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_reconcilied" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 form-check-input" placeholder="Is reconcilied" id="id_is_reconcilied">
            </div>


    <label class="sr-only">Search</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Filter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: remove `mb-2` class from checkbox input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `mb-2` class from your checkboc input and add `mt-1` class will align your checkbox.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline" method="get">
    <!-- Action button placed inside of form so it renders inline with table filters -->
    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-sm-2" href="/journal/entries/new/" role="button">New Journal Entry</a>
    
        <label class="sr-only" for="id_user">User:</label>
        <select name="user" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="User" id="id_user">
            <option value="" selected>User</option>
            <option value="4">philip</option>
        </select>
    
        <label class="sr-only" for="id_type">Type:</label>
        <select name="type" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Type" id="id_type">
            <option value="">Type</option>
            <option value="BP">Bank Payment</option>
            <option value="BR">Bank Receipt</option>
            <option value="YE">Year End</option>
            <option value="JE">Journal Entry</option>
        </select>
    
        <label class="sr-only" for="id_datefrom">Datefrom:</label>
        <input type="date" name="datefrom" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Datefrom" id="id_datefrom">
    
        <label class="sr-only" for="id_dateto">Dateto:</label>
        <input type="date" name="dateto" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Dateto" id="id_dateto">
    
        <label class="sr-only" for="id_search">Search:</label>
        <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" id="id_search">
    
            <label class="sr-only" for="id_ledger">Ledger:</label>
            <select name="ledger" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Ledger" id="id_ledger">
                <option value="" selected>Ledger</option>
                <option value="3">Agata&#x27;s Account</option>
                <option value="5">Agata&#x27;s Credit Card</option>
                <option value="35">Agatas Float</option>
                <option value="75">Agatas Hobbies</option>
                <option value="23">Agatas Salary</option>
            </select>
        
            <label class="sr-only" for="id_project">Project:</label>
            <select name="project" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Project" id="id_project">
                <option value="" selected>Project</option>
                <option value="4">Project Icarus</option>
                <option value="5">Black Star</option>
            </select>
        
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="id_is_reconcilied">Is reconcilied:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_reconcilied" class="form-control mt-1 mr-sm-2 form-check-input" placeholder="Is reconcilied" id="id_is_reconcilied">
            </div>
    <label class="sr-only">Search</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Filter</button>
</form>
```